# Detecting artifact differences between two images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to programmatically detect a "material difference" between two images ignoring cropping and scaling changes.

In other words, if image A shows a tree, a car, and a cloud, and image B is just a (slightly) cropped and (slightly) smaller copy of A (but all other features are untouched) and lower quality, then I want to consider these a match.  But if B has a different cloud, or the car has moved (etc), then the images are different.

Example: Here is image A:

[image: image A]

And here, image B, is just a cropped and resized version of A:

[image]

But now, here image C is not only cropped/resized but also has a yellow asterisk.

[image]

I would like to detect changes of the kind between A and C, but ignore the differences between A and B.  I have tried imagemagick subimage search but it is both (1) extremely slow and (2) fails to find the subimage no matter what metric I use (probably because image B has higher jpg compression, aka lower quality).  A perceptual hash scores the images as "similar" despite the asterisk because the pictures are largely similar.  Perhaps something based on feature detection with OpenCV might be my best bet?

Comment: ImageMagick compare -subimage-search is a simple template matching. Templatemagick only works for translation, not rotation and not scaling. That is why it does not work in ImageMagick. You can try hierarchical (multi-resolution) matching, but you will have to script you loop over scaling, if you do not know the scale factor you used. If you do know that, then either do not scale or scale the B image to match that of the original before using compare.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42.  Unfortunately I cannot introduce a manual step into the process since I have a large number of image pairs to evaluate.  I suppose this is another area in which human visual ability outstrips the ability of a computer (at least with freely-available software).

Comment: If the issue is unknown scale, then you can use feature matching with Python/OpenCv and ORB to get the scale, then scale the image by resizing. Then use Python/OpenCV matchTemplate to find the best match location.

Comment: Here between A & B you are keeping the objects (at different scale) same, only changing (cutting) the background. So using Image Registration technique you can find the matching between the objects, their Relative Positions & then Scale Factor. After that you resize B with that Scale Factor. Also crop A as per size of B (keeping the object(s) position same). Finally Image-subtraction will give you the odd object (which is present only in one image; here yellow star).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Histograms work well for this kind of change detection. Differences in rotation, sharpness and scale won't have much effect, but things like adding a yellow star will show strongly.

For example, [using ruby-vips](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-vips) (since I know it well):

```rb
require "ruby-vips"

a = Vips::Image.new_from_file ARGV[0], access: :sequential  
b = Vips::Image.new_from_file ARGV[1], access: :sequential

# peak normalised difference in histograms
mx = (a.hist_find.hist_norm - b.hist_find.hist_norm).abs.max

puts "peak difference = #{mx}"
```

I see:

```
john@kiwi:~/try$ ./hdiff.rb ~/pics/A.png ~/pics/B.png 
peak difference = 53.0
john@kiwi:~/try$ ./hdiff.rb ~/pics/B.png ~/pics/C.png 
peak difference = 140.0
```